# Audio interface suddenly stopped working on Linux but works fine on Windows

Tags: linux, audio, sound-card

I have an external audio interface ([Line6 UX2](https://line6.com/pod-studio/ux2/)) to use my XLR mic on my desktop.

This used to work fine with my Linux install without issue, however one day it stopped for seemingly no reason, and gave me these error messages on boot which show up in dmesg:

```
[26505.512356]  toneport_init+0x99/0x21b [snd_usb_toneport]
[26505.512362]  ? line6_toneport_disconnect+0x60/0x60 [snd_usb_toneport]
[26505.512433] snd_usb_toneport 3-4:1.0: receive length failed (error -11)
[26505.513232] snd_usb_toneport 3-4:1.0: read request failed (error -32)
[26505.513235] snd_usb_toneport 3-4:1.0: write request failed (error -11)
[26505.516360] snd_usb_toneport 3-4:1.0: Line 6 POD Studio UX2 now attached
[26505.516383] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd_usb_toneport
```

So while the interface is picked up by Pulseaudio, Discord and whatever else as a valid device, no sound will ever come out and my mic will never work using it. It does however function perfectly on my Windows dual boot setup on the same machine.

To try and narrow the problem down, I plugged the interface into my laptop running Gentoo (my desktop runs Debian) which also uses purely ALSA instead of Pulseaudio. The exact same error messages appeared in dmesg, so this is purely a problem with the Linux kernel, or somehow something with the device that's broken that only causes problems with the Linux kernel.

I also tried passing through the interface via USB port to a Windows VM hosted on my desktop, but it exhibited the same behavior as when it's trying to be used by Linux there as well.

Any suggestion on how I can fix this to work with Linux would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry to hear about this. Are there drivers you can try to install on Linux for this device? If it works on Windows but not on Linux it seems like a driver issue. Or possibly a configuration file issue on Linux? If you can find the config file for this device, I would recommend renaming it to something the system won’t pick up on and then rebooting and trying again. That should force the system to create a new config file and (possibly) clear things up.

Comment: The drivers come as modules for the Linux kernel, and are what I've been using the whole time. The two Linux machines I tested had different kernel version, too. Where would I be able to locate such a config file for a device? Do you mean the file that alsa makes, or something else?

Comment: So PulseAudio itself is not picking things up? Have you looked over this [PulseAudio Troubleshooting guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting)? It’s for ArchLinux but I will assume that some of the tips provided can be considered generic.

Comment: No, pulseaudio does pick the interface up. I can set basic configurations like volume from the sound control panel, it just doesn't seem to do anything to make the device work. I don't think it's a pulseaudio problem as my laptop which runs pure ALSA has the same problem with the interface.